# Let $N$ be an Abelian normal subgroup of $G$. If $G/N$ is perfect, then also $G'$ is perfect.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Hans Kurzweil's The Theory of Infinite Group, where it says

> 1.5.3 Let $N$ be an Abelian normal subgroup of $G$. If $G/N$ is perfect, then also $G'$ is perfect.
>
> Proof. From 1.5.1, applied to the natural epimorphism, we obtain 
>   $$G/N = (G/N)' = G'N/N$$ and thus $G = G'N$. Since also $G'/N \cap G' (\cong G/N)$ is perfect, the same argument gives $G' = G''(N \cap G')$. It
>   follows that $G = G''N$ and $G/G'' \cong N/N \cap G''$. Now 1.5.2
>   implies $G' = G''$ since $N$ is Abelian. $\square$

My first question is the motivation of the theorem.

By motivation, for example, about commutator subgroup $G'$, wiki explains,

> The commutator subgroup is important because it is the smallest normal
>   subgroup such that the quotient group of the original group by this
>   subgroup is abelian. In other words, $G/N$ is abelian if and only if
>   $N$ contains the commutator subgroup. So in some sense it provides a
>   measure of how far the group is from being abelian; the larger the
>   commutator subgroup is, the "less abelian" the group is.

So if a group/subgroup is perfect, it's quite "non-abelian".

What is the motivation of the theorem here? 1.5.3 says if $G/N$ is perfect, i.e. quite non-Abelian, then also $G'$ is perfect, i.e. quite non-Abelian, what's the idea of linking $G/N$ with $G'$? What is the character of Abelian normal subgroup this theorem is describing? or it's simple a useful tool like some integral formula that would be used later?

Secondly, what is the relationship between $G/N$ and $G'$? $G=G'N$, does it mean $G = G' \times N$?

Comment: No, $G’N$ is the set $\{gn\mid g\in G’, n\in N\}$; it need not be isomorphic to the (or equal to the internal) direct product of $G’$ and $N$, except in the case where $G’\cap N=\{e\}$. That need not be the ase in general.

Comment: You would want to see where this theorem is used in the book; off the top of my head, I would note that since $N$ is abelian, it is solvable, and hence the solvability of $G$ would depend on that of $G/N$. This tells you that if $G/N$ is perfect, then the derived series of $G$ gets “stuck” after a single application, which gives you a fair amount of information on $G’$ (being perfect is more than simply a measure of non-abelianness, as you will no doubt see further along in the book).